# operator overloading for nested derived templates

Tags: c++

I've got some problem with operator overloading for **derived and nested** class. I've tried many ways but failed many times. Can anyone help to solve this? Here's the code:

***class A***:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
  public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A<T>& a) {
  out << "in A\n";
  return out;
}
```

***class B***:

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const B<T>& b) {
  out << "in B\n";
  return out;
}
```

And test code:

```
A<int> *pa = new B<int>();
B<int> *pb = dynamic_cast<B<int> *>(pa);
cout << *pa << typeid(*pa).name() << endl;
cout << *pb << typeid(*pb).name() << endl;
```

And I got what I need from result:

> in A
>
> 1BIiE
>
> in B
>
> 1BIiE

Then I created a nested class which is also derived from **class A**:

***class BB::B***:

```
template <typename T>
class BB {
  public:
    class B : public A<T> {};
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const typename BB<T>::B& b) {
  out << "in BB::B\n";
  return out;
}
```

But when I test this class with code:

```
A<int> *pa2 = new BB<int>::B();
BB<int>::B *pb2 = dynamic_cast<BB<int>::B *>(pa2);
cout << *pa2 << typeid(*pa2).name() << endl;
cout << *pb2 << typeid(*pb2).name() << endl;
```

I got only an unexpected result:

> in A
>
> N2BBIiE1BE
>
> **in A**
>
> N2BBIiE1BE

Seems that compiler didn't specialize overloaded operator<< for **BB::B**. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const typename BB<T>::B& b);
```

The type of `b` is in a non-deduced context.  It will never deduce `T` from this signature.

You can call it buy passing `T` explicitly.  Or you could write a type map from `BB<T>::B` to `B` and get real fancy.  But that isn't really worth it.

---

The easy option is a Koenig operator.

```
template <typename T>
class BB {
  public:
    class B : public A<T> {
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const B& b){
        out << "in BB::B\n";
        return out;
      }
    };
};
```

this Koenig operator is a non-template function that is generated for each instantiation of `BB<T>::B`, and can be found only via ADL.

Comment: It seems non-deduced context is the final answer. Btw, how to "call it by passing `t` explicitly"?

Comment: The operator should be a friend.

Comment: @dancy `operator<< <T>` or something like it.